# Tar Transform: how to Add a counter to all files in TAR archive

Tags: shell, tar

I am trying to generate a tar file based on a text file with entries, where each file will have a counter on it's beggining :

```
arq2.odt  -> becomes 1.arq2.odt
arq1.odt  -> becomes 2.arq1.odt
```

and such number is increased by 1 for every line of this file.

```
#!/bin/ksh
file="./textobash.txt"
var=1;
while IFS= read line
do
        # display $line or do somthing with $line
    tar -r --transform='flags=r;s|^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$|$var:"\1"|' -rcf file.tar arq1.odt /*
    # increase count
    var=$((var+1))
done <"$file"
```

What I attempted above was to use the --transform documented in the tar website, to append a var value to the file name, so it becomes 1.filename.ext 2.filename.ext, however, tar does not seem to work with regex neither does the append.

Is there any way I can do this? I believe that I will have to recursively append files to my tar archive using the -r flag, however dynamically using variables with the --transform does not seem to work.

Comment: Do you mean that you store `000001.file.ext 000002.file.ext` into your tar file and later you want to add `000003.file.ext` automatically? Your question has numerous problems, so please update with very small set of input sample filenames, the output required, any additional actions your require AND your best attempt to solve the problem in coding. We're not here to write the code for you, but we're here to help you get better at doing so. If my example is correct, then consider storing the last filenumber processed in a temp file. Can you see why a `000001` numbering scheme might be better?

Comment: This is what I want to do ( see edit on original post)